# Thymeleaf Layout Dialect 'An Error Happened During Template Parsing'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

[image: pic1]

This error happens when I try to use layout for my example project.

I've been searching for possible solutions but I couldn't find any solution that is out there that can help me with my situation.

This is my folder hierarchy;

[image]

**This is my index.html;**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:layout="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      layout:decorate="~{layout/layout}">
<head>
    <title>Keep It Simple and Steady.</title>
</head>

<body>

   <!-- Content
   ================================================== -->
                <div layout:fragment="content">
                    <article th:each="post : ${posts}" class="entry">

                        <header class="entry-header">

                            <h2 class="entry-title">
                                <a th:href="|@{/posts/view/}${post.slug}|" th:text="${post.title}">Hey, We Love Open Sans!</a>
                            </h2>

                            <div class="entry-meta">
                                <ul>
                                    <li th:text="${post.publishDate}"></li>
                                    <span class="meta-sep">&bull;</span>
                                    <li th:text="${post.author.nameAndSurname}"></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>

                        </header>

                        <div class="entry-content">
                            <p th:text="${post.teaser}"></p>
                        </div>

                    </article> <!-- end entry -->
                </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**This is my layout.html file;**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 8 ]><html class="no-js ie ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="no-js ie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]><html class="no-js ie ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 8)|!(IE)]><!-->
<html class="no-js" lang="en" xmlns:layout="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>

        <!--- Basic Page Needs
        ================================================== -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Keep It Simple.</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">

        <!-- mobile specific metas
       ================================================== -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

        <!-- CSS
         ================================================== -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{../static/css/default.css}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{../static/css/layout.css}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{../static/css/media-queries.css}">

        <!-- Script
        ================================================== -->
        <script th:src="@{/static/js/modernizr.js}"></script>

        <!-- Favicons
         ================================================== -->

    </head>

    <body>

        <!-- Header
        ================================================== -->
        <header id="top">

            <div class="row">

                <div class="header-content twelve columns">

                    <h1 id="logo-text"><a href="index.html" title="">Keep It Simple.</a></h1>
                    <p id="intro">Put your awesome slogan here...</p>

                </div>

            </div>

            <nav id="nav-wrap">

                <a class="mobile-btn" href="#nav-wrap" title="Show navigation">Show Menu</a>
                <a class="mobile-btn" href="#" title="Hide navigation">Hide Menu</a>

                <div class="row">

                    <ul id="nav" class="nav">
                        <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="has-children"><a href="#">Dropdown</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Submenu 01</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Submenu 02</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Submenu 03</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="demo.html">Demo</a></li>
                        <li><a href="archives.html">Archives</a></li>
                        <li class="has-children"><a href="single.html">Blog</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="blog.html">Blog Entries</a></li>
                                <li><a href="single.html">Single Blog</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="page.html">Page</a></li>
                    </ul> <!-- end #nav -->

                </div>

            </nav> <!-- end #nav-wrap -->

        </header> <!-- Header End -->

        <!-- Content
        ================================================== -->
        <div id="content-wrap">
            <div class="row">

                <div id="main" class="eight columns">
                    <div>
                        <div layout:fragment="content"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div> <!-- end content-wrap -->


        <!-- Footer
        ================================================== -->
        <footer>

            <div class="row">

                <div class="twelve columns">
                    <ul class="social-links">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github-square"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-flickr"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-skype"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="six columns info">

                    <h3>About Keep It Simple</h3>

                    <p>This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet.
                        Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem
                        nibh id elit.
                    </p>

                    <p>Lorem ipsum Sed nulla deserunt voluptate elit occaecat culpa cupidatat sit irure sint
                        sint incididunt cupidatat esse in Ut sed commodo tempor consequat culpa fugiat incididunt.</p>

                </div>

                <div class="four columns">

                    <h3>Photostream</h3>

                    <ul class="photostream group">
                        <li><a href="#"><img alt="thumbnail" src="images/thumb.jpg"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img alt="thumbnail" src="images/thumb.jpg"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img alt="thumbnail" src="images/thumb.jpg"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img alt="thumbnail" src="images/thumb.jpg"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img alt="thumbnail" src="images/thumb.jpg"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img alt="thumbnail" src="images/thumb.jpg"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img alt="thumbnail" src="images/thumb.jpg"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img alt="thumbnail" src="images/thumb.jpg"></a></li>
                    </ul>

                </div>

                <div class="two columns">
                    <h3 class="social">Navigate</h3>

                    <ul class="navigate group">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Demo</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Archives</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <p class="copyright">&copy; Copyright 2014 Keep It Simple. &nbsp; Design by <a title="Styleshout" href="http://www.styleshout.com/">Styleshout</a>.</p>

            </div> <!-- End row -->

            <div id="go-top"><a class="smoothscroll" title="Back to Top" href="#top"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a></div>

        </footer> <!-- End Footer-->


        <!-- Java Script
        ================================================== -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script th:src="@{/static/js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js}"><\/script>')</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/static/js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/static/js/main.js}"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

**And lastly, this is the dependency that I have in my pom.xml;**

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

**LOG INFO**

It didn't allow me to paste the whole so you can get the log via [this link.](https://savetext.ru/FX57ayrU)

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about you try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:layout="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      layout:decorate="~{layout/layout}">
<head>
    <title>Keep It Simple and Steady.</title>
</head>

<div layout:fragment="content">
    <article th:each="post : ${posts}" class="entry">

        <header class="entry-header">

            <h2 class="entry-title">
                <a th:href="|@{/posts/view/}${post.slug}|" th:text="${post.title}">Hey, We Love Open Sans!</a>
            </h2>

            <div class="entry-meta">
                <ul>
                    <li th:text="${post.publishDate}"></li>
                    <span class="meta-sep">&bull;</span>
                    <li th:text="${post.author.nameAndSurname}"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </header>

        <div class="entry-content">
            <p th:text="${post.teaser}"></p>
        </div>

    </article> <!-- end entry -->
</div>
</html>
```

Rest of the other stuff should be handled by your layout. So you might want to update your layout.html to be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en" xmlns:layout="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Keep It Simple.</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">


    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="content-wrap">

            <div class="row">

                <div id="main" class="eight columns">
                    <div>

                        <div layout:fragment="content"></div>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- end main -->

            </div> <!-- end row -->

        </div> <!-- end content-wrap -->

    </body>

</html>
```

**Update**:

From the error logs the error is due to:

```
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Could not parse as expression:
    "@{../static/js/modernizr.js" (template: "layout/layout" - line 28, col 49)
```

Please check and update with the actual layout.html.

Also `@{}` requires full path and not relative path and the path would be starting with what's under `static` folder unless you haven't provided a value for the parameter `spring.mvc.static-path-pattern` in `application.properties`. 
So it would be `@{/js/modernizr.js}`

Comment: With your answer, I discovered that `content-wrap` was inserted twice, both in index and layout. I changed it and applied your suggestion but it didn't help either.

Comment: Can you share more log information? It should provide the root cause of the error.

Comment: Firstly you didn't provide us with the actual layout.html being used. I have updated the answer with the issue

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I did some changes after copying them, just to make it easy for people to read through and turns out I accidentally deleted  ` <div id="content-wrap"></div>` as well.

Comment: It gives me 404 error for the js and css files when I delete the `../` before them. I've changed index and layout with the actual ones.

Comment: If its under static you refer to them directly like `@{/js/}` or `@{/css/}` and so on.

Comment: I was just about to add that as an answer. Can you add this to your solution so I can accept it as an answer?